# Python3 from Thread class to Process

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have some independent threads that would probably gain some speed if I can put them into Process.

I changed class x(Thread): with a def run(self): into a class x(Process)... but the Process doesn't seem to call the run().

What's the correct syntax to set up the Process?

```
def __init()__:
    Process.__init()__(self, Target=self.run, args=(self,)): ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might just be lacking to call `instance.start()` where `instance` is the variable which you earlier set to an instance of your `class x`.

It's easier to answer if you provide a bit more (code) context. From what I see you're mixing up two different ways to setup and start a new thread or process. This is not necessarily bad, it may be intentional. But if it's not, then you're typing more than you need to.

One way is:

```
p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
p.start()
p.join()
```

with `f` being any function. The first line sets up a new `Process` instance, the second line forks and thus starts the (sub)process, and the `p.join()` waits for it to finish. This is the exact example of [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class)

In the second use case, you subclass from `class Process`, and then you do not usually specify a `target` when calling the constructor. `run` is the default method which is invoked as a fork when you actually call the `process.start()` method.

```
class MySubProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self)
        # some more specific setup for your class using args/kwargs
    def run(self):
        # here's the code that is going to be run as a forked process
        pass
```

Then run with

```
p = MySubProcess(any_args_here)
p.start()
p.join()
```

If you do not need any arguments then there's no need to define an `__init__` constructor for your subclass.

Both approaches allow to switch between threading.Thread and multiprocessing.Process datatypes with very few code changes. Of course the way data sharing works changes, and communication is different for threads and processes.

Comment: Thanks, I just came back here to add an answer myself :-) I just seemed like it was not working, in reality, the eclipse/pydev breakpoint inside the run() method was screwing things up. By placing print() functions, I was able to see what was going on.